# Дубли/некорректная обработка 404

Tags: битрикс

Всем доброго времени суток.
Проблема на сайте. Любая страница доступна при дописывании чего угодно к урлу, к примеру 
site.ru/test.php имеет доступна по site.ru/test.php/qqqq , site.ru/test.php/w1w1 и т.д 
подскажите как можно решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

У вас наверно, на главной стоит какой-то компонент с включенным ЧПУ. Если у вас там, например, стоит комплексный компонент news, то да, так и будет. Можно включить тогда в параметрах компонента галочку "Устанавливать статус 404, если не найдены элемент или раздел". Только учтите, что в этом случае компонент просто будет отдавать статус 404 (его будут понимать поисковики и т.д.), но не полноценную 404-ю страницу с каким-то текстом, с этим проблема в битриксе с ЧПУ, можно только специальные костыли ставить, чтобы сделать такую страницу.